# "Cannot find compilation library location for package "enc.dll"" error occur .net core dependency injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I am building a website using asp.net core mvc, and for the login i added dependency for enc.dll file, which just encrypt/decrypt user information.
I made a Seeder class with enc.dll file, which has a key property and en/decrypt with the key. Then I added it to  my service to use dependency injection feature.

```
services.AddSingleton<ISeeder, Seeder>();
```

While it works well when i call enc, dec function of seeder class, it does not return any error. Below is the example code.

```
    private readonly ISeeder seed;
    public AccountController(ISeeder seed)
    {
        this.seed = seed;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult test()
    {
        string s = seed.Enc("testEncode");
        return Json(s);
    }
```

So it works when i return string s that is created by seed instance.

but it is not working when i try to return a view without using seed instance and throwing an error, where Enc is the dll library i am using.

```
InvalidOperationException: Cannot find compilation library location for package 'Enc'
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.CompilationLibrary.ResolveReferencePaths(ICompilationAssemblyResolver resolver, List<string> assemblies)
```

And below is my Seeder code.

```
 private Enc enc;
    private readonly EncKey key;
    public Seeder(IOptions<EncKey> options)
    {
        enc = new Enc();
        key = options.Value;
    }

    public string Dec(string toDec)
    {
        return enc.Dec(toDec, key.EncryptKey);
    }

    public string Enc(string toEnc)
    {
        return enc.Enc(toEnc, key.EncryptKey);
    }
```

Could anyone help? I am working on .net core 2.0 environment

Comment: this issue was fixed in 2.0.3, for apply need to update VS and project packages via nuget

Comment: @itikhomi thanks, It works now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**

> This issue was fixed in 2.0.3, for apply need to update VS(or manualy
>   dotnet SDK and Runtime) and project packages via nuget(in particular
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.All to 2.0.3)

It's known issue of .Net Core 2.0 https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/issues/2981

Razor view precompilation can not resolve lib path

Here workaround to get this work:

add this (it's fixing release publish error)

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.Resolution;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace somenamespace
{
    public class MvcConfiguration : IDesignTimeMvcBuilderConfiguration
    {
        private class DirectReferenceAssemblyResolver : ICompilationAssemblyResolver
        {
            public bool TryResolveAssemblyPaths(CompilationLibrary library, List<string> assemblies)
            {
                if (!string.Equals(library.Type, "reference", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    return false;
                }

                var paths = new List<string>();

                foreach (var assembly in library.Assemblies)
                {
                    var path = Path.Combine(ApplicationEnvironment.ApplicationBasePath, assembly);

                    if (!File.Exists(path))
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                    paths.Add(path);
                }

                assemblies.AddRange(paths);

                return true;
            }
        }

        public void ConfigureMvc(IMvcBuilder builder)
        {
            // .NET Core SDK v1 does not pick up reference assemblies so
            // they have to be added for Razor manually. Resolved for
            // SDK v2 by https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/pull/876 OR SO WE THOUGHT
            /*builder.AddRazorOptions(razor =>
            {
                razor.AdditionalCompilationReferences.Add(
                    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(
                        typeof(PdfHttpHandler).Assembly.Location));
            });*/

            // .NET Core SDK v2 does not resolve reference assemblies' paths
            // at all, so we have to hack around with reflection
            typeof(CompilationLibrary)
                .GetTypeInfo()
                .GetDeclaredField("<DefaultResolver>k__BackingField")
                .SetValue(null, new CompositeCompilationAssemblyResolver(new ICompilationAssemblyResolver[]
                {
                    new DirectReferenceAssemblyResolver(),
                    new AppBaseCompilationAssemblyResolver(),
                    new ReferenceAssemblyPathResolver(),
                    new PackageCompilationAssemblyResolver(),
                }));
        }
    }
}
```

and this (it's fixing compilation errors)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection.PortableExecutable;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation;

namespace somenamespace
{
    public class ReferencesMetadataReferenceFeatureProvider : IApplicationFeatureProvider<MetadataReferenceFeature>
    {
        public void PopulateFeature(IEnumerable<ApplicationPart> parts, MetadataReferenceFeature feature)
        {
            var libraryPaths = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            foreach (var assemblyPart in parts.OfType<AssemblyPart>())
            {
                var dependencyContext = DependencyContext.Load(assemblyPart.Assembly);
                if (dependencyContext != null)
                {
                    foreach (var library in dependencyContext.CompileLibraries)
                    {
                        if (string.Equals("reference", library.Type, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            foreach (var libraryAssembly in library.Assemblies)
                            {
                                libraryPaths.Add(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, libraryAssembly));
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            foreach (var path in library.ResolveReferencePaths())
                            {
                                libraryPaths.Add(path);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    libraryPaths.Add(assemblyPart.Assembly.Location);
                }
            }

            foreach (var path in libraryPaths)
            {
                feature.MetadataReferences.Add(CreateMetadataReference(path));
            }
        }

        private static MetadataReference CreateMetadataReference(string path)
        {
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
            {
                var moduleMetadata = ModuleMetadata.CreateFromStream(stream, PEStreamOptions.PrefetchMetadata);
                var assemblyMetadata = AssemblyMetadata.Create(moduleMetadata);

                return assemblyMetadata.GetReference(filePath: path);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

also change addMVC to this

```
//workaround https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/issues/2981 will be fixed in 2.0.1
            services.AddMvc().ConfigureApplicationPartManager(manager =>
            {
                var oldMetadataReferenceFeatureProvider = manager.FeatureProviders.First(f => f is MetadataReferenceFeatureProvider);
                manager.FeatureProviders.Remove(oldMetadataReferenceFeatureProvider);
                manager.FeatureProviders.Add(new ReferencesMetadataReferenceFeatureProvider());
            });
```

and you will able to use dll in your view

also you have second way is disable razor precompilation here example
[Deleting PrecompiledViews.dll from ASP.Net Core 2 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46700399/deleting-precompiledviews-dll-from-asp-net-core-2-api)

Comment: thanks it works, though new "MvcConfiguration" class doesn't seem necessary. I read the article, applied the solution, and mine does work without "MvcConfiguration" class

Comment: @ringord,try to publish release without "MvcConfiguration" class , in my case i always got errors in publish

Comment: You mean it works in local environment without MvcConfiguration class, but it doesn't in server?

Comment: @ringord, try to create publish folder profile in your project, then try to publish to folder without MvcConfiguration and you will get error Error The command ""dotnet" exec --runtimeconfig "\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\XXX.runtimeconfig.json" --depsfile "\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\XXX.deps.json" "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.viewcompilation\2.0.0\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation.dll" @"obj\Release\netcoreapp2.0\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.viewcompilation.rsp"" exited with code 1.

Comment: @ringord, i mean that MvcRazorCompileOnPublish will not work without MvcConfiguration