# Symbols not Loading within TagHelper class Methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

Runtime: .net-core 2.0, C# 7.1
Visual Studio 2017 15.4.1

Within my solution I have a net-core Library project 'Accounting.Core' and a Asp.Net MVC net-core project 'Accounting.Web'

Within Accounting.Core I have a non-namespace effecting folder 'Tags', within which I have the following class declared:

```
namespace Accounting.Core
{
[HtmlTargetElement("table", Attributes = "asp-table")]
    public class AspTableTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            if(!output.Attributes.ContainsName("href"))
                throw new Exception("asp-table must contain a valid href to load data from");

            var action = output.Attributes["href"];

            //Breakpoint set on this line below
            var content = output.Content;

        }
    }
}
```

In my web project's _ViewImports.cshtml file I have the following:

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, Accounting.Core
```

And finally I have the following razor code in a view:

```
<table asp-table>
    <tr>
        <td><a asp-action="Index" asp-controller="IncomeType">Test</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

However, when I build in debug mode on defaults, the debugger complains that I don't have symbols loaded for my TagHelper class, and I won't hit the breakpoint. Rendering said view also doesn't provide any help either. Nothing happens notable.

How do I make this work?

Comment: i think it same error with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47170668/cannot-find-compilation-library-location-for-package-enc-dll-error-occur-ne/47172061#47172061

Comment: The "no symbols loaded" debugger error is not an application issue. The debugger is just telling you that it can't actually debug some of this code because symbols weren't produced during build. That's usually caused by having "Optimize code" checked in your project properties, under the "Build" tab.

Comment: Looks like thats so, because those last two lines of the Process method are cast to unused variables, the compiler optimizes them away. This seems to be a property of a net-core dll project and not a web project. If I move this class to my web proj it doesnt optimize the lines away.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is as follows:

When compiling to a net-core library project (.dll), the compiler optimizes away lines of code cast to unused variables.

If I moved my breakpoint up to the if statement instead it actually works it seems.