# netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0 is missing when compiling Razor view

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a ASP.NET core self-host app in windows service by following this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/hosting/windows-service). The project `TargetFramework` is .NET framework 4.7.1 and it can serve http requests as expected.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net471</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win81-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

The only problem is from Razor template engine, when the app is compiling the razor view, the following exception is thrown.

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.CompilationFailedException: One or more compilation failures occurred:
widmeur4.h03(4,62): error CS0012: The type 'Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
widmeur4.h03(4,81): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported
widmeur4.h03(4,112): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Type' is not defined or imported
widmeur4.h03(4,11): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported
widmeur4.h03(8,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
widmeur4.h03(9,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
widmeur4.h03(10,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
widmeur4.h03(11,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
widmeur4.h03(14,36): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ViewFeatures' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
widmeur4.h03(15,96): error CS1980: Cannot define a class or member that utilizes 'dynamic' because the compiler required type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DynamicAttribute' cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?
widmeur4.h03(15,96): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Boolean' is not defined or imported
widmeur4.h03(15,47): error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
widmeur4.h03(18,67): error CS1983: The return type of an async method must be void, Task or Task<T>
widmeur4.h03(18,39): error CS0400: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)
widmeur4.h03(29,49): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ViewFeatures' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
widmeur4.h03(29,118): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported
widmeur4.h03(31,49): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'IUrlHelper' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
widmeur4.h03(31,71): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported
widmeur4.h03(33,49): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'IViewComponentHelper' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
widmeur4.h03(33,87): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported
widmeur4.h03(35,59): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'IJsonHelper' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
widmeur4.h03(35,83): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported
widmeur4.h03(37,59): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'IHtmlHelper<>' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
widmeur4.h03(37,71): error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
widmeur4.h03(37,71): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported
widmeur4.h03(37,71): error CS1980: Cannot define a class or member that utilizes 'dynamic' because the compiler required type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DynamicAttribute' cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?
widmeur4.h03(37,71): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Boolean' is not defined or imported
widmeur4.h03(37,92): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported
widmeur4.h03(18,67): error CS0508: '_Views_Status_Index_cshtml.ExecuteAsync()': return type must be 'Task' to match overridden member 'RazorPageBase.ExecuteAsync()'
widmeur4.h03(18,67): error CS0012: The type 'Task' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
widmeur4.h03(28,58): error CS0012: The type 'Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
widmeur4.h03(28,10): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported
widmeur4.h03(30,58): error CS0012: The type 'Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
widmeur4.h03(30,10): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported
widmeur4.h03(32,58): error CS0012: The type 'Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
widmeur4.h03(32,10): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported
widmeur4.h03(34,58): error CS0012: The type 'Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
widmeur4.h03(34,10): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported
widmeur4.h03(36,58): error CS0012: The type 'Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
widmeur4.h03(36,10): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported
widmeur4.h03(20,13): error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
widmeur4.h03(20,13): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported
widmeur4.h03(20,26): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Int32' is not defined or imported
widmeur4.h03(20,31): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Int32' is not defined or imported
widmeur4.h03(20,34): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Boolean' is not defined or imported
widmeur4.h03(20,13): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported
widmeur4.h03(21,13): error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
widmeur4.h03(21,13): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported
widmeur4.h03(21,26): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported
widmeur4.h03(21,13): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported
widmeur4.h03(22,13): error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
widmeur4.h03(22,13): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported
widmeur4.h03(22,13): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported
widmeur4.h03(23,13): error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
widmeur4.h03(23,13): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported
widmeur4.h03(23,26): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Int32' is not defined or imported
widmeur4.h03(23,31): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Int32' is not defined or imported
widmeur4.h03(23,34): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Boolean' is not defined or imported
widmeur4.h03(23,13): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported
widmeur4.h03(24,13): error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
widmeur4.h03(24,13): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported
widmeur4.h03(24,26): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported
widmeur4.h03(24,13): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported
widmeur4.h03(25,13): error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
widmeur4.h03(25,13): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported
widmeur4.h03(25,13): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported
widmeur4.h03(18,67): error CS0161: '_Views_Status_Index_cshtml.ExecuteAsync()': not all code paths return a value
widmeur4.h03(15,18): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler.CompileAndEmit(RazorCodeDocument codeDocument, String generatedCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler.CompileAndEmit(String relativePath)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler.CreateCacheEntry(String normalizedPath)
```

My Visual Studio 2017 version is 15.3.
.NET Core SDK 2.0 are installed.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

---

*UPDATE*:

I tried to modify the csproj file according to this [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/1212#issuecomment-297885722).

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <!--
    Work around https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4412. MVC uses DependencyContext.Load() which looks next to a .dll
    for a .deps.json. Information isn't available elsewhere. Need the .deps.json file for all web site applications.
  -->
  <Target Name="CopyDepsFiles" AfterTargets="Build" Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'!=''">
    <ItemGroup>
      <DepsFilePaths Include="$([System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension('%(_ResolvedProjectReferencePaths.FullPath)', '.deps.json'))" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Copy SourceFiles="%(DepsFilePaths.FullPath)" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)" Condition="Exists('%(DepsFilePaths.FullPath)')" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

The same issue still happens

Comment: can you provide dotnet version by runnig "dotnet --version" in cmd?

Comment: Can you try updating to the CLI version 2.1.2 and your VS to 15.5? It contains a lot of fixes for netstandard2.0 on net471

Comment: I think you faced with that issue if you using .NET Core version below 2.0.3 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47170668/cannot-find-compilation-library-location-for-package-enc-dll-error-occur-ne/47172061#47172061

Comment: Thanks everyone above,  I found the reason.  So the Razor is used in assembly B.dll,  and the A.exe assembly is the entrypoint of the process.   Adding the `deps.json` file for either B.dll or A.exe will not work.  It works after I added `CopyDepsFiles` for both B.dll & A.exe